# How to filter a string with multiple words in any given order for javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filtering, frontend

I have a simple filter for the `alt` attribute in `<img>`. I put and `<INPUT>`. 
everything works when I search for one word,but when I type another word that is the same `"alt"` it doesn't show anything. Example 
`alt = "pyramid green"`

1. if I type GREEN it shows the picture
2. if i type PYRAMID it shows the picture
3. if I type PYRAMID GREEN it shows the picture

   **4. if I type GREEN PYRAMID it DOESN'T SHOW anything**

what I want to is to search any given word inside the `alt` attribute in any given order. thanks for the help.

```
function search() {
var filter =  $('input').val().toUpperCase();
var li = $('li');
var a = $('a');
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ) {    
        li[i].style.display = '';

    } else {
        li[i].style.display = 'none';

    }
}
```

}

Comment: So you want pattern searching with a space delimiter? So GREEN PYRAMID should match but GREE PYR shouldn't?

Comment: if the alt attibute has the word I want it to match doesnt matter in what order, if GREEN PYR should match still unless you write GREEN PYRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split the *filter* string on spaces, as now you search the whole string.

So your code will be:

```
function search() {

    var filter =  $('input').val().toUpperCase().split(' ');
    var li = $('li');
    var a = $('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i];
        var text = a.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
        for(var f = 0; f < filter.length; f++) {
            if (text.indexOf(filter[f]) > -1 ) {    
                li[i].style.display = '';
                break; // don't need further matches
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }

}
```